# JavaFX, How can I use "import java.util.Random;", 'Cannot resolve symbole "java".' under Gradle

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, javafx

I just need a random variable, but when i try to import something from java... I got this error. Im working with gradle, javafx and intelliJ.
When I try to "/gradlew build" I got the same error.
The function "System." doesnt even work. `System.out.print("");`

Comment: Can you provide a [mre], please?

Comment: package model;

import java.util.Random;

public class Court {}`

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be either

- that you have not started with good build.gradle
- or there are some import issues with IntelliJ

Here is a simple gradle build that works with both gradle build and run.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

javafx {
    version = "14"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

group 'com.fx'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

mainClassName = 'com.fx.HelloFX'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.fx.HelloFX',
        'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' ')
    }
} }
}
```